# perl OOP pass variable

Tags: perl

This is SeqIO.pm

```
package SeqIO;
use strict;
use Carp;
use warnings;
use vars('@ISA');
use vars('@EXPORT_OK');
require Exporter;

@ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT_OK = qw(readSeq writeSeq);

sub readSeq {
    my ($var1)= @_;
    print "$var1\n";
    open IN, '<$var1' or die "Cannot open file : $!";
    while(<IN>) {
        chomp $_;
        print "$_\n";   
    }
    close IN
}

sub writeSeq {}

sub new {
    my $this = {};
    bless $this;
    return $this;
}

1;
```

Test.pl call SeqIO.pm

```
use strict;
use SeqIO;
use warnings;
my $path_fasta=q/D:\360Downloads\A1.fasta/;
my $seqio = new SeqIO;

$seqio->readSeq($path_fasta);
```

BUT when i use readSeq it shows SeqIO=HASH(0x38ba34), anything wrong?

Comment: Aside: There should be a `local $_;` in there to avoid clobbering data in the caller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call a Perl subroutine as a method using the `->` operator, the *invocant*, meaning the thing on the left side of `->` is passed into the subroutine as the first parameter. So change your method to this:

```
  sub readSeq {
      my ($self, $var1) = @_;
      print "$var1\n";
      open my $in, '<', $var1 or die "Cannot open file : $!";

      while(<$in>) {
          chomp $_;
          print "$_\n";   
      }
  }
```

I've also changed your filehandle to a lexical variable instead of a global symbol, and changed your `open` call to the three-argument version which is better.

There's also no need to export `readSeq` and `writeSeq` if you intend to use those as object methods. Exporting is only for when you want to modify the client code's namespace. So you can delete all of this:

```
use vars('@ISA');
use vars('@EXPORT_OK');
require Exporter;

@ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT_OK = qw(readSeq writeSeq);
```